# Formula to paste contents from clipboard broken

Tags: excel, vba

My formula just broken and i dont know why

```
Sub COLAR()

Worksheets("FORMULAS").Range("A3:M90").ClearContents

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORMULAS").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("CC").Range("A1"), _
 Scroll:=True

End Sub
```

The result I was getting is:

[image: BEFORE]

But now all the contents are being placed in one cell:

[image: AFTER]

So, this formula paste the contents from clipboard on a table, but suddenly i started to get this error "pastespecial method of worksheet class failed error 1004"

For reference, this is where I copy, is a PHP Table from internet,
And the macro place on "Table37" (or A3) on my workbook, that matches the coluns so every content is placed inside Table37
[image: COPY]

I made a table to match the colunms when i paste.

This code basically serves to do what is being shown in the following images, I manually paste it keeping the formatting of the destination, and pasting like this it respected the columns and rows as I copy from the PHP table from the internet which is where I extract the infos:

[image: 01]
[image: 02]

Comment: Possible typo: `past` or `paste`?

Comment: What is in the clipboard/  What do you copy before running this code?

Comment: I tried to include more information, hope it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by specifying that the data in my clipoard comes from an HTML table

```
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
```

My final code

```
Sub COLAR()

Dim DataObj As MSForms.DataObject
Set DataObj = New MSForms.DataObject
DataObj.GetFromClipboard

SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FORMULAS").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
        False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
        
Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("CC").Range("A1"), _
 Scroll:=True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The paste special command is not needed if you assign the value directly

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value = SText
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)  'not needed, remove
```

The code below should suffice

```
Sub COLAR()
  
  Worksheets("FORMULAS").Range("A3:M90").ClearContents

  Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
  DataObj.GetFromClipboard

  SText = DataObj.GetText(1)

  Worksheets("FORMULAS").Range("A3").Value = SText

  Application.Goto Reference:=Worksheets("CC").Range("A1"), _
    Scroll:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Tried that, but it is placing only on A3 like the 2° img

Comment: I also tried using just paste instead of pastevalues, I was pasting respecting the columns of image 1, but I was replacing the table format

Comment: @Cooper what is the clipboard? The `GetText(1)` command clued me that you are pulling a single text value? Please edit your question and add more details. The code above assumed data for 1 cell was stored on the clipboard and assigned to cell `A3`.

Comment: Updated the question, hope it help, many thanks so far